# Align two colums (the second of them, with two items) to the base line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to recreate something like the screenshot attached. Please, note the block with "another text" is aligned with the left column. Each grey box will be an image. Also take into consideration that the text can be multiple lines.

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/chux/qgbw0moz/51/

The problem is that, when the first colum have more lines than the second one, the bottom of the boxes will be aligned, not the bottom of the images.

How can align them?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: strech;
}

.row>.col {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.row-col {
  background: grey;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.first-col {
  background: red;
}

.second-col {
  background: green;
}

.third-col {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container row">

  <div class="col first-col">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/450/480/animals">
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="row-col">

      <div class="col second-col">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/180/animals">
      </div>

      <div class="col third-col">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/180/animals">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: expected result]

Comment: Would you be confortable using absolute positionning or ellipsis ? Check out this ellipsis example : https://jsfiddle.net/6bcfvwyg/1/. I integrated your images using `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`

Comment: @Jake that wasn't the solution I was hoping so, but so far, it seems the only solution

Comment: This is the solution I ended up with: https://jsfiddle.net/chux/qgbw0moz/68/

Answer (score 0):

So, here goes, nice and simple - just give a fixed height to the text shown under each photo. You will have to decide about this height depending on your 'average text height' and use `overflow:hidden` or use the highest value possible.

```
.subtitle {
  line-height:20px;
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/7wqmf1Lr/

**edit:** here is another way to fake it. For the first column instead of using an `img`, just use a `div` element with a background image. Safely assuming that the second column might have variable height, expand the `div` with the background image on first column to consume all of the first column's height and then add a second row for either single or multi-text beneath. This might be a bit tricky for responsive -eg change the background image `div`'s height to absolute value or add multiple layers of the same text to hide/show on specific resolutions (or use JS instead), but is certainly doable and a direct solution to your problem.

If you like I can help you with the implementation of the responsiveness as well - although out of the scope of this question.

Replaced `img` tag with `div` and `background-image`:

```
<div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/400/480/animals)">
</div>
```

Added css:

```
.img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/7wqmf1Lr/13/

Comment: The content will still break if the text is longer because it can span 2 lines on desktop but 3 on mobiles for example.

Comment: That's it, the problem is that the text is variable. I can't / shouldn't make it a fixed height

Comment: Well, on smaller resolutions, the correct way would be to stack blocks of content right? Also, this solution is dependent on the text - I mean, there shouldn't be TOO much text here. If it's just ONE section (which would essentially mean low effort for maintenance) then a more customized solution could be implemented.

Comment: Yep, they will stack. But I don't know if it is going to be two or three lines. Also, three lines in a big screen (this is 1560px wide) would produce, maybe 5 on an ipad.

Comment: So, I hadn't realized up to this point that this was meant to fill a whole container - I assumed due to lack of description that this component would make use of a smaller fraction of the container - eg like medium's blog. Then another question comes in mind, would the images used be the exact same ratio as the ones in the examples?

Comment: Truth is, you will have to make a compromise, either add 'extra height' to accommodate possible multi-line text, or maybe absolutely position text over images at the bottom, but this would cause the images not to be aligned. If this is meant for a hero for a website for example and the content is specified only then you might be able to style specifically for this layout.

Comment: This is supposed to be responsive, with a maximum of 1560px wide on desktop. I don't know the ratio of the images, I only have a simple mockup sent by a client

Comment: @Chux could you show us a screenshot of the mockup ?

Comment: But, if you use two different rows (one for the big image, one for the subtext) the way you are using it, when i have to stack them on the mobile version, the images and description won't match

Comment: @Chux I have already said that in the answer, that implementing the responsiveness might be challenging, but is out of the scope of this question. However, it's doable - either by duplicating content and showing/hiding at specific resolutions or using js. Clients don't know the challenges of layouts. So either explain it and have a slight variation, or design what is asked with compromises. Using fixed heights is your next best bet.

Comment: I know that, i will possibly go for the figcaption with absolute position, I was just wondering if that was possible with flex

Comment: yeah, I know :( Will try with the absolute position and post the final solution. Thanks everyone for your time

Comment: @scooterlord You have to take into account that an image background is really not the same as a true image especially when it comes to content and SEO, a background image is good when it's purely decorative IMO

Comment: @Jake agreed. But imho design & content > SEO.